# Importing SQLite3 data into Excel 2010 (via Microsoft Query and ODBC driver)

Tags: excel, sqlite, windows-10, microsoft-query

I'm trying to load **SQLite3** database data into **Microsoft Excel 2010 x32** via Microsoft Query (in **Microsoft Windows 10 x64 Creators Update 1703**).

I downloaded and installed the **SQLite ODBC Driver 0.9996** from http://ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/. Microsoft Excel 2010 runs as Win32, so I've tried both variants - Win32 driver only and Win64+Win32 drivers.

I've opened Excel, then go to **Data**->**From other sources**->**From Microsoft Query** (the last item)
[image]

Then I select **SQLite3 Datasource***
[image]

and set path to my database (I don't select any addtitional checkboxes)
[image]

After that first strange thing appears - table list is empty:
[image]

To fill the list I have to uncheck and the check again **tables** checkbox under **parameters...** button
[image]

And then tables are shown correctly as I've expected
[image]

And then the main problem comes out: when I select **only one table** from list - data is loaded correctly
[image]

but if I select **several tables** - no data is loaded (looks like some problem with joining tables)
[image]

So is this ODBC driver still working in Microsoft Windows 10 x64 (and for Microsoft Excel 2010 x32)?
Or maybe I'm missing some additional checkboxes?

P. S. I've uploaded my test SQLite3 database here - https://yadi.sk/d/aO0zDSof3Tz2FY